Have Terminal command run on startup (on MacOS)
I want to have a command run on my computer on startup, without me having to login.
I want to do this because I want to have a program running all the time on my computer without me needing to login in the case that I restart my computer (instead of paying for a cloud computing service).

You can use launchd for this.
It sounds like you want to make a system daemon, which means you need to create a file in /Library/LaunchDaemons. Summarising this guide:

Let's say you want to create a service called Foo
Which runs a Python script stored at /Users/bar/foo.py (i.e. you'd run python3 /Users/bar/foo.py to start this script)


Create a file at /Library/LaunchDaemons/Foo.plist with the following:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Foo</key>
    <string>com.bar.foo</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>python3</string>
        <string>/Users/bar/foo.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>


Register the daemon using:

sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/Foo.plist


Start the daemon:

sudo launchctl start com.bar.foo


Check the daemon is running

sudo launchctl list

If it doesn't show in the list, try restarting
